# How to send data from the flask frontend to the python backend, end get results back?

Tags: python, json, flask, request

I am new to web development and I have created a frontend using html/css/js and flask. I run my frontend through my flask app, app.py. This is the part of a app.py which controlls the behaviour of the compare.html where we need to select two options from two drop down menus and a number beta. They are inside of a form tag and in the app.py option1, option2 and beta variables read those two selected options.

```
@app.route('/compare.html', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def compare():
    if request.method=='POST':
        option1 = request.form.get('option1')
        option2 = request.form.get('option2')
        beta = request.form.get('beta')
        #print(request.data)
        return redirect("compare.html?sim1={}&sim2={}".format(option1, option2)) 
    else:
        return render_template("compare.html")
```

I need to send those two values to a backend code which is written in python and run a model from those parameters. Backend file is json_experiment.py and I need to call methods according to the options user selects. Then a json file will be created in the backend which I need to import to the frontend render the final output. How can I do this task or how can I integrate frontend and backend? Do I need to create an API for this?

Comment: You need to use an ajax solution, or build-in fetch method of javascript if you want to do this without reflesh page. Because you are not able to live communicate with browser when you use only python, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @Buğraİşgüzar I will try that. Did you mean to create an API when you mentioned build-in fetch method of javascript? BTW to get the inputs from the user from the compare.html, I have included a button in the form tag. It will refresh the page right? or not? when python redirect the page can I send the newly formed json with that?

Comment: Yes, any case, you need to create an endpoint to handle form data. Form data might be come directly from form or comes from fetch method of javascript. If you add a target and method attributes for form element, yes it will reload page when you submit the form and send form datas to your target. When you handle form data on backend, you can prepare new HTML and return it. Not json.